# Melpa obsolete packages

Tags: package-repositories

Using Emacs 26.3, suddenly any package I install from Melpa shows `Available Obsolete from melpa -- Install`. All used to be fine. What is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

That message confused me too. It turns out it's just a poor choice of words for saying that there's a new version available.

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2019-02/msg00082.html

Once you update the list of packages with `M-x package-refresh-contents`, then you can type `U x` and it will upgrade all installed packages that have a more recent version available.

Once that is one, the message you see when you open the description of an updated package will be:

> Package x is installed.